# Define scoped npm registry URL as environment variable

Tags: npm, travis-ci

We have a scoped module, and for `npm` to be be able to resolve it, we have to say where its repo is. This can be done in i.e. `.npmrc`, such as:

```
@my-scope:registry=http://my-sweet-replication.example.com/npm/
```

My problem is that because of some proxying and authentication for GET requests, I have to put different values in `.npmrc` for development versus the build server (travis enterprise). We already take advantage of the fact that `npm` can read environment variables for packages that are not scoped, but as both `@` and `:` are invalid characters in an environment variable I'm unable to export the correct URL.

Any ideas on how to tell npm where to look for scoped modules without putting it in `.npmrc`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For now, my solution is to use the `env` command, i.e. (in `.travis.yml`)

```
install: env 'NPM_CONFIG_@MY-SCOPE:REGISTRY=http://my-sweet-replication.example.com/npm/' npm install
```

Is that the only way to do it?

Putting it in the travis `env` matrix does not work, as it uses `EXPORT`, so it tries to export just `REGISTRY`

(Posting my answer as I didn't get any hits from googling)

Comment: I've been having difficulty with this as well.  The choice to use special characters like `@` and `:` is troublesome since these are not valid environment variable characters.  Isn't there some way to escape the bad characters?

Answer (score 1):

Create the user by hand, by installing a `~/.npmrc` with the appropriate token.

First, go into your project's envvars, and set the token under some name.  For this example I use `NPM_TOKEN`, but that's not important.  Some unices break with lowercase envvars, so use allcaps.

Next add the following to your `.travis.yml`:

```
before_install:
  - echo "//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${NPM_TOKEN}" > ~/.npmrc
```

Now you should have an NPM user with the appropriate credentials.